# load2neo not working - how to properly use?

Tags: python, neo4j, batch-processing

I am using [load2neo](http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo) for batch importing geoff format text files into neo4j.

I have followed the instructions on the load2neo site, which include dropping two jar files into the neo4j server's plugin directory, and updating the server configuration file with an extra line.

When I try to load the file using curl, then nothing happens. It doesn't issue an error and just gives me a new line in the terminal.

I am wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong? Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of others trying the same thing:

I made the mistake of thinking that I had to include the CREATE statements in the geoff formatted file. These are not required, in other words, for a node:

```
(a:Label{"prop":"someProp"})
```

or for a relationship:

```
(a)-[:REL]-(b)
```

No need for stating CREATE, MERGE, etc.

Note that uniqueness is supported with the use of the bang symbol, per the load2neo and [geoff docs](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff).

Comment: I don't have the cypher statements in my file, even though I get nothing after running the bulk load line. My geoff file is not at the same place as my database, is that a problem? My server is on, when go to the directory where my `geoff` file is and I run:



`curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/load2neo/load/geoff -d`



and nothing happens, what am I missing? Thank you!